# Inheriting code-behind class from PhoneApplicationPage's subclass

Tags: c#, xaml, subclass, code-behind, windows-phone-8

By default all code-behind classes inherit from `PhoneApplicationPage`. I would like to make a subclass of `PhoneApplicationPage` and use it as basis for my code-behind class, like so:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class HistoryRemoverPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo
            (NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
}

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : HistoryRemoverPage 
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile my application I get the following error:

> Error 1   Partial declarations of 'Test.MainPage' must not specify
>   different base classes

I believe this has to do with following declaration in `MainPage.xaml` that points to `PhoneApplicationPage` instead of my subclass:

> phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...

But I don't understand how to fix this. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track. You need to change the root element in your `MainPage.xaml` to your custom base class:

```
<test:HistoryRemoverPage x:Class="Test.MainPage"                   
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    <!-- ... ---> 
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test">

         <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
         <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
              <!-- ... --->
         </Gird>    

</test:HistoryRemoverPage>
```

Note you need add your base class namespace (`xmlns:test`) in order to specify your base class in XAML.

Comment: Hi nemesv, I cant get the solution. In xaml, when mouse hover to <test, it says: The type 'test' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all assembly references has been built.

Comment: Are you sure that you have included the `xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test"` and it correctly points to your assembly which contains your base class? Have you tried to rebuild your project?